# Ubuntu 14.10 touchscreen not recognized anymore on XPS 15 9530 Haswell

Tags: kernel, dell, 14.10, touchscreen

I've a Dell XPS 15 with Ubuntu 14.10 and I've just realized that my touchscreen does not work anymore. It's not even recognized:

```
$ dmesg |grep -i touch
[    3.179897] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126800, board id: 2733, fw id: 1515627
[    3.283270] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
```

Here is the output of xinput:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Webcam                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

As you can see, there is no entry for Synaptics touchscreen, as expected under "Virtual core pointer".

I tried re-installing Dell's quirck for touchscreen with no effect.
My kernel version was 3.16, I upstreamed to latest 3.18 kernel with no results.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Luis

Comment: Well, 2 days past and no clues yet. I'm affraid touchscreen is really dead, since it's not appearing anymore on xinput list. I was expecting a line like this :`⎜ ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen id=9 [slave pointer (2)]`. I think I will contact Dell's support. I would appreciate if someone who has gone through the same issue drop a comment. Thanks !

Comment: Another day and no solution to my issue. Got a clue: kernel module usbhid is not loaded at startup: `$ lsmod |grep usb
btusb                  32691  0 
bluetooth             486890  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm`. tried modprobe usbhid, it loads the module, but still no touchscreen available as a device ...

Comment: Just for information, problem not solved yet. Contacted Dell support: they can't help me on Linux, but they insist is a software issue, not a hardware issue. Since them, I'm struggling to recover my Windows disk image on a usb external drive so I can boot on Windows 8 (!!!) and have the diagnose on Dell tools... not easy at all and not cool.

Comment: If like me, you're trying to boot your dd-cloned Windows 8 from a external USB drive (and thus having INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE error), then this link you help  you: http://superuser.com/questions/808953/running-windows-8-on-external-hdd

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: in my case it was a hardware issue and Dell support replaced my screen today.

To have Dell support helping me, I had to recover the original Windows 8 disk image on an external USB drive (to avoid destroying my Linux), and yesterday, Dell support took control of the machine and confirmed with their tools that it was not a software issue. And today, they replaced the screen. Very fast service indeed!

Now I can see again the Synaptics touchscreen device that had disappeared:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 06cb:0ac3 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:573c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
$ dmesg|grep -i synaptics
[    1.719155] usb 1-6: Product: Synaptics Large Touch Screen
[    1.719157] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: SYNAPTICS
[    3.191978] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126800, board id: 2733, fw id: 1515627
[    3.293994] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[   13.980801] input: SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/0003:06CB:0AC3.0001/input/input8
[   13.994469] hid-multitouch 0003:06CB:0AC3.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
```

That's a pity that Dell does not provide support for Linux on XPS 15 as for XPS 13 Sputnik. Once they had their hands on my computer over Windows 8, they were very reactive.

Important to notice that it was a nightmare to make my Windows 8 disk image to work on an external USB3 drive (at least, I saved my current linux disk image):

- almost a full day copying data with dd;
- 3 days in a boot/reboot loop having INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE blue screen error and only windows in safe mode until a found a trick to modify Windows 8 registry (see the comments) that allowed me to boot on windows 8 normally;

So now I continue using Linux and I keep an USB external drive with windows 8 and dell tools, ready to use in case of needing dell's support.

Hope no one face this kind of issue, but if so, hope this helps.